# Rank & Retrieve, Failed to connect to gateway.watsonplatform.net

Tags: solr, ibm-watson

I am trying to create a Create Solr cluster using java class as given in steps on below link [as shown here](https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/retrieve-and-rank/api/v1/?java#create_solr_cluster)

but i am getting following error, can this be firewall issue?

**Using JAVA**
com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService execute SEVERE: IOException java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to gateway.watsonplatform.net/:443 at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:139) at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:108) at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184) at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126) at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95) at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281) at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224) at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:286) at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:243) at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:205) at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:80) at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService.execute(WatsonService.java:122) at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService.executeRequest(WatsonService.java:183) at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.retrieve_and_rank.v1.RetrieveAndRank.createSolrCluster(RetrieveAndRank.java:168) at Test.artf.CreateASolrClusterExample.main(CreateASolrClusterExample.java:20)

**Using CURL**
When i try using curl command as below that also gives connection error as below.

curl -X POST -u "":"" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/retrieve-and-rank/api/v1/solr_clusters" -d ""

Response:
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host

when i put the link in curl command in crome, it pop up for id/password. After giving id/password returns me

{"clusters":[]}

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please format the code within your question.

Comment: This question is likely more appropriate for IBM's [dW Answers support site](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/). Disclosure: I am an evangelist for IBM Watson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service is experiencing some issues currently; the team is aware and working on it. Sorry for the trouble, please try again in a little while.